# How can I generate a plot of positive predictive value (PPV) vs various cut-off points for classifications?

Tags: r, classification, roc

I have generated some scores to help predict whether or not something is yes (1) or no (0), let's say the data consists of:

```
scores = c(10:20)

response = c(0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1)

mydata = data.frame(scores, response)
```

I can do an ROC analysis, which gives an AUC of .77:

```
roc(response = mydata$response, predictor = mydata$scores)
```

Now, how exactly do I see what happens when various cut-offs are chosen? I'd like to have cut-offs on the x-axis (let's say 13,14,15,16,17) and PPV on the y-axis. What's a nice way of doing this? What functions/packages do I need?

Comment: A couple of useful packages for this are `ROCR` and `verification`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will give an answer based around the pROC package*. It is possible to obtain similar results using the ROCR package as well.

You want to use the [`coords`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pROC/versions/1.9.1/topics/coords) function, which can compute several common statistics at some given thresholds. For instance, in order to get the PPV at all thresholds, you can do the following:

```
library(pROC)
r <- roc(response = response, predictor = scores)
coordinates <- coords(r, x = "all", input = "threshold", ret = c("threshold", "ppv"))
```

You can then plot those values:

```
plot(t(coordinates))
```

Replace `"all"` by the thresholds of interest:

```
 coordinates <- coords(r, x = c(13, 14, 15, 16, 17), input = "threshold", ret = c("threshold", "ppv"))
```

<sub>* Disclaimer: I am the author of the pROC package.</sub>

Comment: How awesome to get a reply from the author! Using your work for some important stuff, so thank you very much!

Comment: What if you have you have a list of PPVs, and you want it to return a list of thresholds?

Comment: @PleaseHelp that's a different question. On stack overflow you should ask a new question when you have a follow-up question.