# find top important variables in RF evaluated at new threshold

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, r-caret, proc

If you [change the threshold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459084/how-can-i-generate-a-plot-of-positive-predictive-value-ppv-vs-various-cut-off) of a random forest model trained using `caret::train`, how can you see the most important variables for that model at a new threshold?

You can typically do it with `plot(varImp(rf_model), top = 20)` for an unchanged model, but how do you extract variables at a different threshold?

I know the below code can give you a CM at a new threshold, but I don't know how to utilize that for variable importance...

```html
#create RF
data_ctrl_null <- trainControl(method="cv", number = 10, classProbs = TRUE, summaryFunction=twoClassSummary, savePredictions=T, sampling=NULL)

rf_model <- train(Outcome ~ ., data=dat, ntree = 2000, tuneGrid = data.frame(mtry = 69), 
  trControl = data_ctrl_null, method= "rf", preProc=c("center","scale"), metric="AUC",importance=TRUE)

#set new_threshold
label <- ifelse(rf_model$pred$affirmatory > new_threshold, 'affirmatory', 'negatory')

confusionMatrix(label, rf_model$pred$obs, positive = 'affirmatory')
```

Comment: The importance of variables is the same if the rf model is the same. The threshold will not change that. Furthermore `AUC` does not depend on threshold since it is an aggregate over all thresholds.

Comment: if you make this an answer, I can mark it correct